# Binary to decimal in c

Tags: c, binary

I have a simple code to convert binary to decimal numbers. In my compiler, the decomposition works just fine for number less than 1000, beyond the output is always the same 1023. Anybody has an idea ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// how many power of ten is there in a number 
// (I don't use the pow() function to avoid trouble with floating numbers)
int residu(int N)
{
    int i=0;
    while(N>=1){
        N=N/10;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

//exponentiating a number a by a number b
int power(int a, int b){
    int i;
    int res=1;
    for (i=0;i<b;i++){res=a*res;}
    return res;
}

//converting a number N
int main()
{
    int i;

    //the number to convert
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);

    //the final decimal result
    int res=0;
    //we decompose N by descending powers of 10, and M is the rest
    int M=0;

    for(i=0;i<residu(N);i++){
        // simple loop to look if there is a power of (residu(N)-1-i) in N, 
        // if yes we increment the binary decomposition by 
        // power(2,residu(N)-1-i)
        if(M+ power(10,residu(N)-1-i) <= N)
        {
            M = M+power(10,residu(N)-1-i);
            res=power(2,residu(N)-1-i)+res;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",res);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your program with a debugger? On Linux that would mean compile with `gcc -g -Wall` and then use `gdb` on the binary.

Comment: no I didin't, I use Xcode as a compiler

Comment: Don't write `else{}`, please.

Comment: There should be a way to compile with debugging information and to use some debugger on your system.

Comment: I am really new to xcode, and it seems rather non intuitive to activate the debugger console but why I have been downvoted ?

Comment: Here's what I found in the debugger : libsystem_kernel.dylib`__read_nocancel:
0x7fff9a539278:  movl   $33554828, %eax

libsystem_kernel.dylib`read$NOCANCEL + 5:
0x7fff9a53927d:  movq   %rcx, %r10
0x7fff9a539280:  syscall
0x7fff9a539282:  jae    0x7fff9a539289            ; read$NOCANCEL + 17
0x7fff9a539284:  jmpq   4683
0x7fff9a539289:  ret    
0x7fff9a53928a:  nop    
0x7fff9a53928b:  nop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{ 
char bin; int dec = 0;

while (bin != '\n') { 
scanf("%c",&bin); 
if (bin == '1') dec = dec * 2 + 1; 
else if (bin == '0') dec *= 2; } 

printf("%d\n", dec); 

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this is because you are using an `int` to store your binary number. An `int` will not store numbers above 2^31, which is 10 digits long, and 1023 is the largest number you can get with 10 binary digits.

It would be much easier for you to read your input number as a string, and then process each character of the string.

Answer (score 1):

After a little experimentation, I think that your program is intended to accept a number consisting of 1's and 0's only as a base-10 number (the `%d` reads a decimal number).  For example, given input `10`, it outputs `2`; given `1010`, it outputs `10`; given `10111001`, it outputs `185`.

So far, so good.  Unfortunately, given `1234`, it outputs `15`, which is a little unexpected.

If you are running on a machine where `int` is a 32-bit signed value, then you can't enter a number with more than 10 digits, because you overflow the limit of a 32-bit `int` (which can handle ±2 billion, in round terms).  The `scanf()` function doesn't handle overflows well.

You could help yourself by echoing your inputs; this is a standard debugging technique.  Make sure the computer got the value you are expecting.

I'm not going to attempt to fix the code because I think you're going about the problem in completely the wrong way.  (I'm not even sure whether it's best described as binary to decimal, or decimal to binary, or decimal to binary to decimal!)  You would do better to read the input as a string of (up to 31) characters, then validate that each one is either a 0 or a 1.  Assuming that's correct, then you can process the string very straight-forwardly to generate a value which can be formatted by `printf()` as a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Shift left is the same than multiply by 2 and is more efficient, so I think it is a more c-like answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bin2int(const char *bin) 
{
    int i, j;
    j = sizeof(int)*8;
    while ( (j--) && ((*bin=='0') || (*bin=='1')) ) {
        i <<= 1;
        if ( *bin=='1' ) i++;
        bin++;
    }
    return i;
}

int main(void) 
{ 
    char* input = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;

    while ( getline(&input, &size, stdin) > 0 ) {
        printf("%i\n", bin2int(input)); 
    }
    free(input);
}
```

Comment: Most compilers will optimize a constant multiplication to a shift, when it is faster. And it might not always be.

Comment: You're right. However I just cant use a multiplier when I want to shift bits and I cant use shift when I am doing math... It is just a semantic thing that I cant get rid of.

Comment: Interesting point.. but semantically, we could argue that a multiplication is appropriate here, since it generalizes to bases other than 2 !

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>  //printf
#include <string.h> //strlen
#include <stdint.h> //uintX_t or use int instead - depend on platform.

/* reverse string */
char *strrev(char *str){
    int end = strlen(str)-1;
    int start = 0;

    while( start<end ){
        str[start] ^= str[end];
        str[end]   ^= str[start];
        str[start] ^= str[end];
        ++start;
        --end;
    }
    return str;
}


/* transform binary string to integer */
uint32_t binstr2int(char *bs){
    uint32_t ret = 0;
    uint32_t val = 1;

    while(*bs){
       if (*bs++ == '1') ret = ret + val;
       val = val*2;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(void){
    char binstr[] = "1010101001010101110100010011111"; //1428875423
    printf("Binary: %s, Int: %d\n", binstr, binstr2int(strrev(binstr)));
    return 0;
}
```