# How to convert binary to decimal in C

Tags: c

I would like to convert a series of integers to decimal. I know the procedure but how can I put all integers as one binary number?

Output has to be like this:

```
Enter first binary digit: 0
Enter second binary digit: 0
Enter third binary digit: 0
Enter fourth binary digit: 0
0000 = 0
```

The following is how I wrote this task:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(void)
    {
        int a[100];
        int n, dec = 0; int power(int, int);

        long int binaryNumber, decimalNumber = 0, j = 1, remainder;  

        printf("Enter first binary number: ");
        scanf("%ld", &a[1]);
        printf("Enter second binary number: ");
        scanf("%ld", &a[2]);
        printf("Enter third binary number: ");
        scanf("%ld", &a[3]);
        printf("Enter fourth binary number: ");
        scanf("%ld", &a[4]);

        for (int i = 0;i<n;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }

        for (int i = (n - 1);i >= 0;i--)
        {
            dec = (a[i] * power(2, j)) + dec;
            j++;
        }
        printf("binary number of decimal is %d", dec);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Luia Moly and welcome on stackoverflow, maybe this question can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338584/binary-to-decimal-in-c

Comment: Do you mean `(a - '0') * 1000 + (b - '0') * 100 + (c - '0') * 10 + (d - '0') * 1`?

Comment: The primary error in the program is that 'n' is used uninitialized. The compiler most probably has an option to warn about such errors.

Answer (score 4):

Well, that's simple math. The first binary digit is 2^0, the second 2^1, the third 2^2, ...

```
number = first * 1 + second * 2 + third * 4 + forth * 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int baseN_to_decimal(char *number, int from_base){
    int result = 0;
    int digit;
    int len = strlen(number);
    for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
        // printf("%c", number[i]);
        if(number[i]>='0' && number[i]<='9'){
            digit = number[i] - '0';
        }
        if(number[i]>='A' && number[i]<='F'){
            digit = number[i] - 'A' + 10;
        }
        if(number[i]>='a' && number[i]<='f'){
            digit = number[i] - 'a' + 10;
        }
        result = result + digit * (pow(from_base,len-i-1));
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\r\n", baseN_to_decimal("101010",2)); // Binary to decimal
    printf("%d\r\n", baseN_to_decimal("17AF",16)); // Hex to decimal
    printf("%d\r\n", baseN_to_decimal("17af",16)); // Hex to decimal
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int bin,dec=0,i=0,c,p,a;

    printf("Enter a number in binary to convert into decimal = ");
    scanf("%d",&bin);
    p=bin;
    
    while (bin>0)
    {
        c=pow(2,i);
        a=p%10;
        dec=dec+c*a;
        printf("%d\n",dec);
        bin=bin/10;
        p=p/10;
        i=i+1;
        
    }
    printf("Decimal number = %d",dec);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
//binary to decimal converter
long int bin2dec(long int binary_number,int i){
 if(binary_number == 0)
    return 0;
 else
    return ((binary_number%10)*pow(2,i) + bin2dec(binary_number/10,++i));
}
```

Comment: don't use `pow` for integer computations, use shift.