# How do i convert Binary to ASCII

Tags: c, encoding, binary, ascii

If i have a character 'V' and it's binary number is 01010110
Is there any formula to do it? like masking it with a bit or &?
not sure if there's any bitwise operation for converting binary to ASCII in c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary to decimal in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338584/binary-to-decimal-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is one encoding scheme to map a integer stored in your computer memory to a visual character.

Meaning that using an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you can see that 'V' is mapped to the integer decimal value '86' (note that for a program such table is not needed, as your value is already stored as an integer)

Then is is a matter of converting it to binary which is convered in [other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)

Comment: The link you've sent is converting ASCII to Binary but i'm not sure how do we do the opposite?

Comment: here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19955215/105104

Comment: But that's binary to decimal.